# Kendo Ui Dropdownlist Set Visible via Javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I need to set kendo dropdownlist visible programmatically in javaScript.

I had tried:

```
dropdownlist=$("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.visible(false);
dropdownlist.isVisible(true);
dropdownlist.visible("false");
dropdownlist.isVisible("true");
```

etc...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One should always use the API docs to see the features of a widget. In this case, there is no API method for hiding a widget, but you can hide its wrapper element:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#ddl").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.wrapper.hide(); // call wrapper.show() to make it visible again
```

Comment: There is a limit of minimum question length. So I had to write something else different from the title.

Comment: And also there is no information about hiding dropdown in kendo docs http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist

Comment: I see  - as an alternative, maybe you could just say "I couldn't find anything in the documentation about hiding a widget". My comment was more of a general recommendation though, since it's easy to waste a lot of time by trying to guess API functionality instead of looking it up.

Answer (score 5):

Try like this,

```
$("#ddl").closest(".k-widget").hide();
 $("#ddl").closest(".k-widget").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling to DOM by using style property work for me.

document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown1')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';

document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown2')[0].style.visibility = 'visible';