# Jquery empty() function working too long?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I got weird issue. I'm working with kendo and I've got two cells. First is dropdownlist and the second is depending what I pick in first one. If it's string the second cell is dropdown, if it's int in second cell I got numericbox etc. Now when I'm picking string value second dropdown is showing, but after that when I want to pick another attribute, for example int, the dropdown is not changing on numericbox, just numerixbox is create next to my dropdown.
Screens:

[image: dropdown]

[image: dropdown and numericbox]

I tried to use .empty() function, but after using this the cell is empty all the time, even if I'll pick another attribute. I just want clear grid cell once after choosing new attribute, not clear it for all time. Tried also `$('#myid').html("")` but I got the same effect. Can somebody explain me what can I do?

Comment: Can you show the grid configuration, model classes and crud methods ? Can you reproduce the issue in a kendo dojo ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'll need a refresh to happen after inputting a new value in the first dropdown. On the kendo UI API page, I've found this [reference](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist/events/change).
You can code the second dropdown to subscribe to the change event of the first dropdownlist, then emptying the second dropdownlist wont be needed anymore. The example in the reference already shows using the value of the dropdown as a variable. Seeing that the dropdownlist widget in kendo UI doesn't have a visibility property, you'll need to hide or show the wrapper for the element, see [the answer from Lars Höppner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23342314/kendo-ui-dropdownlist-set-visible-via-javascript).

I've added an example I made based on the references:

```
<input id="dropdownlist" />
<input id="dropdownlist2" />
<script>
  function dropdownlist_change(e) {  
     var dropdownlistToHide = $("#dropdownlist2").data("kendoDropDownList");
     var value = this.value();

     if (value === "Apples"){
       dropdownlistToHide.wrapper.hide();
     } else if (value === "Oranges") {
       dropdownlistToHide.wrapper.show();
     }
  }
  $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [ "Apples", "Oranges" ]
  });

  $("#dropdownlist2").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: [ "Dinges", "Dinges2" ]
  });

  var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
  dropdownlist.bind("change", dropdownlist_change);
  var dropdownlistToHide = $("#dropdownlist2").data("kendoDropDownList");
  dropdownlistToHide.wrapper.hide();
</script>
```

The final dropdownlistToHide.wrapper.hide(); is meant to hide the dropdownlist widget from the start.